# Variable scope in model before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the code in Rails Casts #250 authentication from scratch:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

...

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

In `encrypt_password`, why when generating `password_hash`, the parameter passed to `hash_secret` is `password_salt` instead of `self.password_salt`? Why does it automatically recognizes a instance variable in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has a fallback mechanism. Consider this example:

```
class SomeClass
  def my_method
    "my method"
  end

  def other_method_with_local_variable
    my_method = "lala"
    puts my_method
  end

  def other_method
    my_method
  end
end
```

Now let's test those methods in console:

```
1.9.3p448 :016 >   SomeClass.new.other_method # outputs instance method value, because there were none local variables inside the method and it falled back to instance scope
=> "my method"
1.9.3p448 :017 > SomeClass.new.other_method_with_local_variable # outputs "lala" because it's the value of lcoal variable
lala
```

People who do not understand this concept often overuse `self`, it makes eyes of the seasoned Ruby developers to bleed :D

**UPD**

It seems You are confusing instance methods with instance variables. If You are coming from other OOP languages the closest analogy to instance var would be a private property/attribute. Of course in Ruby it's possible to get to it anyway with some workarounds. Example:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

p = Person.new("John")
#  => #<Person:0x007fbe910cc680 @name="John">
p.name #produces error, because object doesn't have such method, only a private property
#NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Person:0x007fbe910cc680 @name="John">
p.instance_variables # we can always get list of instance variables
# => [:@name]
p.instance_variable_get(:@name) # access them
# => "John"
p.instance_variable_set(:@name, "Ben") # and set them
#  => "Ben"
p
# <Person:0x007fbe910cc680 @name="Ben">
```

It's considered a **very bad habit** to mess with object internals this way, we should use a public interface of the class.
In many languages usually people start defining accessors/setters for such properties. It's quite common to see methods like `set_name`, `get_name` inside classes. Ruby syntax allows and conventions suggest to do it this way:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(new_name)
    @name = new_name
  end
end

1.9.3p448 :015 >   p = Person.new("John")
# => #<Person:0x007f8b8b20ad28 @name="John">
1.9.3p448 :016 > p.name
# => "John"
1.9.3p448 :017 > p.name = "Ben"
# => "Ben"
1.9.3p448 :018 > p
# => #<Person:0x007f8b8b20ad28 @name="Ben">
```

It's quite common to define those in Your objects, so Ruby provide shortcut for that. We can refactor our class like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

1.9.3p448 :009 >   p = Person.new("John")
# => #<Person:0x007f8091233a48 @name="John">
1.9.3p448 :010 > p.name
# => "John"
1.9.3p448 :011 > p.name = "Ben"
# => "Ben"
1.9.3p448 :012 > p
# => #<Person:0x007f8091233a48 @name="Ben">
```

We can actually verify that `attr_accessor` does exactly the same:

```
1.9.3p448 :013 > Person.instance_methods.grep(/^name=?/)
# => [:name, :name=]
```

Now getting back to ActiveRecord. It defines methods in same fashion for Your columns, so for a `name` column it will define methods `name` and `name=`. Difference is though that AR objects are much more complicated and those calls read/write attributes which does more things than just setting instance variable `@name`.

If You have understood the concept of the scope for Your variables/methods, than probably it should be clear to You when to use `self` and what those method calls actually do.

Small summary:

- Instance vars **are not methods**, they could be called private properties of the object
- We define accessor methods to access instance vars, usually using attr_accessor, attr_reader (read-only property) methods
- When accessing some variable Ruby searches in local scope for variable, if not found Ruby  takes a shot thinking it's instance method and calls it on `self`
- You need explicitly say `self` when writing to accessor( `self.name =` ), otherwise Ruby treats it as a creation of local variable. You also need to use `self` when reading if You have a variable of the same name in Your local scope, but it's a very bad practice and I doubt You will come across with such.

Comment: But in this case, `password_salt` is neither a local variable (since the code used `self.password_salt` so no local var is defined) nor a instance method. Why this way of accessing it still works?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood You at first. In this case it's obvious that it must be a column defined on this model. I went to the Railscast source repo and found it: https://github.com/railscasts/250-authentication-from-scratch/blob/master/auth/db/migrate/20110124034948_create_users.rb

You need to use self when assigning because otherwise Ruby will treat it as a local variable. But when reading that value You can omit `self` like Ryan does on line 3 of the method.

Comment: Yeah I know it works. My question is why it works? Why can we omit `self` when reading it without defining a local var or a method?

Comment: As I have written it earlier Ruby has a built-in fallback mechanism. If it can't find a variable in local scope, it tries an instance scope. That is what happens there - Ruby interpreter searches for local variable called password_salt, if it doesn't find one it does the same call on `self`. If You want to understand internals of this mechanism then You need to dive deep into Ruby source code :)

Comment: But if I do this `class Foo @myvar = "hello" def pt puts myvar end end`, and then `foo = Foo.new` and try `foo.pt` there's an error. So I'm confused.

Comment: I added more examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

In short: If you access a method or a local variable you do not need to write `self`. But if you want to assign a value to a method, you always need the `self`. If you do not use `self`, Ruby will assign the value to a local variable.

Comment: Or create one if it's not declared